# How to restart a daemon service if it crashes?

Tags: linux, daemon

I created a little `daemon service` in `Ubuntu` which works pretty well, I have a question about the crash of my application.

This service execute an app that I developed, but could happen that this app will crash, so I need to restart it automatically.

Inside the service I wrote:

```
[Unit]
Description = Hello World Daemon

[Service]
ExecStart = /usr/bin/dotnet /home/my username/Desktop/publish/SimpleApp.dll
Restart = on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

as you can see I have `Restart = on-failure` I want to know if this line is enough to restart the service automatically when the app crash. Thanks.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
[Unit]
...

[Install]
...

[Service]
...
...
Restart=always
RestartSec=3
...
```

The value of the Restart parameter is set to always. This means service will restart for clean or unclean exit codes or timeouts.
That's where an automatic restart is defined in systemd.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not sure if I understood well this, so I ask you a question: your solution always restart the daemon that is already running, or it will start a daemon that is crashed?

Comment: When it crashes. Regards

Answer (score -1):

```
Restart = always
```

That should do the trick.